# F# interface inheritance failure due to unit

Tags: f#, unit-type

Does anyone know why this fails to compile?

```
type MyInterface<'input, 'output> = 
    abstract member MyFun: 'input -> 'output

type MyClass() = 
    interface MyInterface<string, unit> with
        member this.MyFun(input: string) = ()
    //fails with error FS0017: The member 'MyFun : string -> unit' does not have the correct type to override the corresponding abstract method.
type MyUnit = MyUnit
type MyClass2() = 
    //success
    interface MyInterface<string, MyUnit> with
        member this.MyFun(input: string) = MyUnit
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This looks like a nasty corner-case in the F# language, but I'm not sure if it qualifies as a by-design limitation or a bug in the compiler. If it is by design limitation, then the error message should say that (because currently, it doesn't make much sense).

Anyway, the problem is that the F# compiler doesn't generate code that actually contains the `unit` type in the IL. It replaces it with `void` (when used as a return type) or with empty argument list (when used as a method or function argument).

This means that in the `MyClass` type, the compiler decides to compile the `MyFun` member as a method that takes `string` and returns `void` (but you cannot use `void` as a generic type argument, so this just doesn't work). In principle, the compiler could use the actual `unit` type in this case (because that's the only way to get it working), but that would probably create other inconsistencies elsewhere.

Your trick with creating `MyUnit` is, I think, a perfectly fine way to solve the problem. Even the core F# library uses something like `MyUnit` in some places of the implementation (in asynchronous workflows) to deal with some limitations of `unit` (and the way it is compiled).

Comment: Thanks Tomas. I haven't seen this issue elsewhere (e.g. in normal functions with let;)

Comment: @Stefan: If you use the `unit` type as argument (to a function or type) then it is generally fine. This bug/limitation probably appears only when implementing abstract members (which is a bit tricky area for the F# compiler, because inheritance is surprisingly complex in .NET)

Comment: Interestingly, it will work in C# and I can consume the function in F#. Probably should be reported as a bug.