# Under what conditions is unit a type?

Tags: generics, f#

Before this gets marked as a duplicate: I'm aware that this question is related to various questions about compilation errors when using unit as a type argument. Some examples:

- [Why is `unit` treated differently by the F# type system when used as a generic interface argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26296401/4191347)
- [F# interface inheritance failure due to unit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4485445/4191347)
- [Using unit as Type Parameter and overriding methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10012078/4191347)

These are all running into a problem similar to this one:

```
type Interface<'a> = 
    abstract member MyFunc : unit -> 'a

let implementingInstance =
  { new Interface<_> with
        member __.MyFunc () = () } // Compiler error!
```

From what I understand, the code does not compile because a unit-returning function gets compiled with `void` return internally, which is an extra feature of the CLI rather than a type.

However! The following seems to satisfy the compiler:

```
type RecordVersion<'a> =
  { MyFunc : unit -> 'a }

let recordInstance =
  { MyFunc = ignore }
```

This also works if I replace `ignore` with a lambda or a `let`-bound module function.

To me, this is just another formulation of the exact same thing. (Though at odds with the F# design guidelines, which suggest to prefer interfaces over function-carrying record types.)

I'm interested in designing APIs whose users specify the behavior and types used. Therefore, I would like to avoid cases where unexpected and confusing compiler errors occur. But I'm not quite sure what to make of this. It looks like F#'s "functional" functions *do* treat unit as a type.

What are the exact conditions for such spurious errors with unit? Can I avoid them in my API by breaking the design guidelines and using records of functions instead of interfaces? (I wouldn't mind much, but I'm not sure if it solves the problem for good.)

Comment: absurd :: Void -> a (Haskell) I think that is somewhat related ;-)

Comment: Since this is about design of general-purpose APIs, this may be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34028711/126014

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the rule is that a method that is statically known to have return type `unit` will be compiled to a .NET method with return type `void` in the .NET type system (by statically known, I mean in contrast to a generic method or a method on a generic type which uses a type parameter as the return type).  At invocations, the compiler hides the distinction between methods that return `void` and methods that return true `unit` values at the CLR level.

The problem in your example occurs because properly implementing the generic interface actually requires a `unit` return type at the CLR level (and the CLR does care about the distinction between `unit` and `void`).  In other words, the problem occurs if and only if you want to override a method which returns a type parameter of a generic class by a method which is statically known to return `unit` (based on substituting `unit` for that type parameter).  By override here, I mean either implementing abstract methods on classes or interfaces or overriding non-sealed methods on classes.

As Tamil points out, one way to work around this limitation is to ensure that you use F# functions instead of methods.  Another workaround is to introduce an extra concrete class into the hierarchy which has a dummy generic type parameter (say the extra class is `T<'unit>`), and to return `Unchecked.defaultof<'unit>` instead of `()` wherever that would cause problems.  Then you can derive an additional non-generic concrete class `T` from `T<unit>` and everything will work fine.

Comment: This explains it! Thanks, I was kinda hoping you'd stop by to answer this one. :)

Answer (score 3):

The difference between your working and non-working examples is that the non-working one is a *method*, and in this case (and AFAIK only this case) the F# compiler generates IL code that actually takes or returns `void`. In the working case, it is a *property* of type `Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc<unit, unit>` (aka `unit -> unit`) which does not get "optimized" into something taking or returning `void`.

So yes, using records does solve the problem for good. Another possibility would be to make an interface with a property:

```
type Interface<'a> = 
    // Note the parentheses to make this member a property rather than a method
    abstract member MyFunc : (unit -> 'a)

let implementingInstance =
    { new Interface<_> with
        // Must use an explicit `fun () ->` instead of a method arg list
        member __.MyFunc = fun () -> () }
```

If your problem was with taking unit as an argument, then it could be solved by writing a method that takes `(())` as argument (ie. an explicit `unit` value, rather than an empty list of arguments). But for the return value I don't think there is any way to make the method work :/

Comment: It seems that the problem only occurs when implementing abstract member methods? But why is the issue specific to inheritance/interfaces, in addition to generics and methods? Say, I make a `type T<'a>` with a non-abstract member of type `unit -> 'a`. An instance `T<unit>` seems to work! Isn't the member in this case also compiled as a method, and shouldn't it therefore fail as well? I want to be sure about the exact conditions for the problem, as the actual use case is more complicated than the example in the question.