# Passing "unit" as type parameter to generic class in F#

Tags: f#

I have an interface which takes a generic parameter and has an abstract method

```
type MyInterface<'a> =
    abstract member abstractMethod: 'a -> 'a
```

...and I have a derived class which inherits from base class using **unit** for the type parameter

```
type Derived() =
    interface MyInterface<unit> with
        override this.abstractMethod (_) = ()
```

but the compiler complains that

> Error     The member 'abstractMethod : unit -> unit' does not have the
>   correct type to override the corresponding abstract method.

If I use another type instead of unit, **int** for example, the code compiles.

Is this a bug in the compiler? Is there a workaround for it?

Thanks!

Comment: Your override of `abstractMethod` doesn't have the signature `unit -> unit`--it takes an argument of unspecified type (named `_`).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40283165/under-what-conditions-is-unit-a-type and the other questions linked from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`unit` is "special" in terms of interop: when a function takes a `unit` as parameter, it is compiled to IL as a parameterless function, and when a function returns a `unit` as result, it is compiled as a `void` function. As a result of this trickery, you can't really use `unit` as a "general-purpose" type in interop settings (such as classes and interfaces).

In fact, when I try to compile your code on my machine, I get a different error:

```
The member 'abstractMethod : unit -> unit' is specialized with 'unit' 
but 'unit' can't be used as return type of an abstract method
parameterized on return type.
```

Which is trying to say roughly what I described above.

(I'm not sure why you're getting what you're getting; perhaps you're using an older version of F#)