# Why is `unit` treated differently by the F# type system when used as a generic interface argument?

Tags: f#, unit-type

Consider this interface:

```
type A<'a> =
    abstract X : 'a
```

Let's try to implement it with `int` as a generic argument:

```
{ new A<int> with member this.X = 5 } // all is well
```

Now, let's try `unit` for an argument:

```
// Compiler error: The member 'get_X : unit -> unit' does not have the correct type to override the corresponding abstract method.
{ new A<unit> with member this.X = () }
```

Now, if we define a non-generic interface, everything also works well:

```
type A_int =
    abstract X : int

{ new A_int with member this.X = 5 } // works

type A_unit =
    abstract X : unit

{ new A_unit with member this.X = () } // works as well!
```

Is there anything I can do to fix this problem?

Comment: In C# it is not possible to have a generic function returning `void` - see for example https://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/131036/why-is-void-not-allowed-as-a-generic-type-in-c .  It is possible that similar restrictions are being applied to the F# code in this instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In F#, an abstract slot with declared return type of `unit` gets compiled in .NET IL as a return type of `void`. In contrast, an abstract slot with declared return type of "T" gets compiled in .NET IL as a generic return type of "T", which when T is instantiated by `unit` becomes `unit'`.

See : [F# interface inheritance failure due to unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485445/f-interface-inheritance-failure-due-to-unit/4485677#4485677)

Answer (score 0):

Your generic member X can be a value of any type. 'unit' in F# is not really a type (or is very special type if you wish) - it's an absence of any value.