# Methods with return type 'x=unit can't override generic abstract methods

Tags: generics, f#, overriding, abstract

In the following code, `UnitClass1.F` seems to override `BaseClass1<unit>.F`, but actually not. Could someone tell the reason why?

```
// Method case.
type [<AbstractClass>] BaseClass1<'x>() =
  abstract member F: unit -> 'x

type UnitClass1() =
  inherit BaseClass1<unit>()

  // ERROR: F: unit -> unit doesn't have the correct type to override the corresponding abstract method.
  override this.F() = ()

  // ERROR: Wrong number of parameters.
  //override this.F(()) = ()

  // ERROR: UnitClass1 doesn't have an implementation for abstract member F: unit -> 'x
  //member this.F() = ()
```

This issue also occurs on properties.

```
// Property case.
type [<AbstractClass>] BaseClass2<'x>() =
  abstract member P: 'x

type UnitClass2() =
  inherit BaseClass2<unit>()

  // The same error as the above.
  member this.P = ()
```

However, if I move the generic parameter to the parameter side then that code compiles.

```
type [<AbstractClass>] BaseClass3<'x>() =
  abstract member F: 'x -> unit 

type UnitClass3() =
  inherit BaseClass3<unit>()

  // OK
  override this.F(()) = ()
```

Of cause, they compile if `'x` is not `unit`.

```
type [<AbstractClass>] BaseClass4<'x>() =
  abstract member P: 'x

type UnitClass4() =
  inherit BaseClass4<int>()

  // OK
  override this.P = 0
```

ENVIRONMENT: Windows 10, F# 4.0, Visual Studio 2015 community

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485445/f-interface-inheritance-failure-due-to-unit