# Why is F# erroring on this member override?

Tags: inheritance, f#

**Context:**

I am trying to create a couple classes to encapsulate SQL commands in way that fits better with functional programming than the standard `System.Data` classes.

There are 3 main types of SQL commands that I care about,

- commands that return nothing
- commands that return 1 row
- commands that return many rows

The implementation for how these must be executed is slightly different, but I want them to all share a common contract, which is why I am using class inheritance. I could also use an interface, but it doesn't seem like a big difference in this case.

I have implemented the shared contract as this base class:

```
[<AbstractClass>]
type ClosedCommand<'a>(text, kind, parameters) =
    inherit OpenCommand(text, kind, parameters)

    abstract member execute : cn:IDbConnection -> 'a
```

And the 3 sub-classes as:

```
type UnitCommand(text, kind, parameters) =
    inherit ClosedCommand<unit>(text, kind, parameters)

    override x.execute cn =
        let cmd = x.toCommandDefinition null
        SqlMapper.Execute(cn, cmd) |> ignore 

type SingleCommand<'a>(text, kind, parameters) =
    inherit ClosedCommand<'a>(text, kind, parameters)

    override x.execute cn =
        let cmd = x.toCommandDefinition null
        SqlMapper.QuerySingle<'a>(cn, cmd)

type PluralCommand<'a>(text, kind, parameters) =
    inherit ClosedCommand<seq<'a>>(text, kind, parameters)

    override x.execute cn =
        let cmd = x.toCommandDefinition null
        SqlMapper.Query<'a>(cn, cmd)
```

The core of the implementation is the `SqlMapper` class from the Dapper library.

**Problem:**

I am getting a compilation error on the subclass for commands returning nothing.  Here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

The message is:

*The member `execute : IDbConnection -> unit` does not have the correct type to override the corresponding abstract method.*

It looks to me like it does have the correct type. Even if I add type annotations, it still gives the same error.

The only difference between this case and the other two is that it is binding `unit` to `'a`, whereas the other two leave it generic. That doesn't seem like it should matter.

**Minimal example:**

```
[<AbstractClass>]
type CommandBase<'a>(name) =
    member this.Name : string = name
    abstract member Execute : unit -> 'a

type UnitCommand(name) =
    inherit CommandBase<unit>(name)
    override this.Execute () = ()

type SingleCommand<'a>(name, x) =
    inherit CommandBase<'a>(name)
    override this.Execute () = x 

type MultipleCommand<'a>(name, xs) =
    inherit CommandBase<seq<'a>>(name)
    override this.Execute () = xs
```

How can I get this to compile?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485445/f-interface-inheritance-failure-due-to-unit